# CKEDITOR for wordpress Can't remove <p>&nbsp;</p>

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have such html:

```
<main class='someClass'>
  <!-- somecontent -->
</main>
```

After updating the post I see:

```
<p>&nbsp</p>
<main class='someClass'>
<p>&nbsp</p>

  <!-- somecontent -->

<p>&nbsp</p>
</main>
<p>&nbsp</p>
```

What can I do? What's this?
I read a lot of posts about this problem, but, I think, I don't understand only one: WHERE I have to insert all the rules? Such as

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.extraAllowedContent = 'main';
```

or else? Because then I inserted in **ckeditor.config.js** I see no changes. It continue to insert to my html

```
<p>&nbsp</p>
```

Can somebody help me? I'll be very thankfull.

Comment: What versions (CKEditor for WordPress and WordPress itself) are you using?

I've just checked your code with WordPress 4.5.2 and CKEditor for WordPress 4.5.3.3 and there is no additional `<p>&nbsp</p>` after switching to/from Visual/HTML, neither showing Source inside CKEditor.

Comment: I have the same versions, that you wrote. I think you don't noticed that I said about tag "main". All else tags writes normally. You can check it in your example. If don't have anything - take me your access. Sure, if you can.

Comment: Do you have any additional plugins installed? Or some other configuration changes?
I've just checked with content inside, instead of `<!-- somecontnet -->` comment, like: ```<main class="someClass">
 <p>
  Maybe there is a problem with the some content
 </p>

 <div>
  <p>
   Another paragraph
  </p>
 </div>
</main>```
And it worked just fine - no `<p>&nbsp;</p>` inserted.

Comment: The code was fine when switching between source/WYSIWYG modes in CKEditor or between HTML/Visual in WordPress, but was wrong after save during edit.

Answer (score 0):

After longer investigation I think I found it.

**Steps taken:**

Firstly I checked if CKEditor supports HTML5 tags at all, and it does. So it should not strip them or change at all. As you posted the `<main class="someClass">` was getting surrounded with `<p>&nbsp;</p>` - this could happen if `main` was recognized as an inline element instead of block one. I digged into `CKEDITOR.dtd` and it turned out that `main` exists and it is a block element. It should be fine.

To check if it's a CKEditor issue or WordPress I checked what was written into database and what the CKEditor was getting from it. The post/page content was as in the example below (the only difference was the new lines characters - as CKEditor formats the code):

```
<main class="someClass">
    <p>There should be only 2 paragraphs inside the</p>
    <pre>&lt;main class=&quot;someClass&quot;&gt;&lt;/main&gt;</pre>
    <p>element.</p>
</main>
```

But the code returned for edit was different

```
<p><main class="someClass"></p>
<p>There should be only 3 paragraphs inside the</p>
<pre>&lt;main class=&quot;someClass&quot;&gt;&lt;/main&gt;</pre>
<p>element.</p>
<p></main></p>
```

The `<main class="someClass">` was wrapped with `<p></p>`, then CKEditor was fixing those paragraphs around block element and the result was as you posted:

```
<p>&nbsp</p>
<main class='someClass'>
<p>&nbsp</p>
```

After short debugging of WordPress core I found the place where those paragraphs were added - function `wpautop` inside `formatting.php`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/

To be more precise, the [469 line](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L469) which describes all block elements:

```
$allblocks = '(?:table|thead|tfoot|caption|col|colgroup|tbody|tr|td|th|div|dl|dd|dt|ul|ol|li|pre|form|map|area|blockquote|address|math|style|p|h[1-6]|hr|fieldset|legend|section|article|aside|hgroup|header|footer|nav|figure|figcaption|details|menu|summary)';
```

and there is no `main` element.

**So you have some options:**

1. Disable wpautop at all (not recomended)
2. Edit WordPress sources and add this element to the list. Then remember about it after every WordPress upgrade.

Or report it, create patch/pull request and wait for the fix, then update without any risk ;)